# :paramName doesn't match URL segments containing dot '.' in react app with Vitejs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, vite

### :paramName doesn't match URL segments containing dot '.'

I have a route `<Route path="/:id" component={Query} />` in my `App.js` 
When I try to navigate to `localhost:3000/abc.xyz`, the page shows page not found 
Note: The project is using vitejs

Answer (score 9):

Add the plugin `https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-rewrite-all`.
To vite.config.js file. And you are all set.